# Re-compilation in Numba

Tags: python, numba

I have a basic question about numba, unfortunately I could not find the answer up to now. Consider the following code:

```
import numba

@numba.jit(nopython=True)
def f1(x):
    y = 0
    for _ in range(1000):
       y += f2(x)
    return y

@numba.jit(nopython=True)
def f2(x):
    return x
```

Will the function f2 be re-compiled every time f1 calls in in the loop, or will it just be compiled once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When `f1` gets called for the first time and gets compiled, it will by necessity compile `f2` and the entire compiled function including `f2` will be cached in memory. Each subsequent call of `f1` (unless called with a value of `x` that is of a different type than previous invocations) will not result in the recompilation of any code.